# INSERT with PL/SQL Anonymous Block

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

My task is to create some tables and insert data into them with a PL/SQL anonymous block. I can get the tables created, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get the data inserted. Every method I've tried raises an error in some fashion. Currently, I have the following code:

```
DECLARE
    create_student VARCHAR2(500) := 'CREATE TABLE student(stu_id CHAR(5),Lname VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,Fname VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,Mi VARCHAR(2),Sex CHAR(1),Major VARCHAR(10),Home_State VARCHAR(4),CONSTRAINT stu_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (stu_id))';
    create_course VARCHAR(500) := 'CREATE TABLE course(course_id VARCHAR(8),section CHAR(3)NOT NULL,c_name VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL,c_description VARCHAR(50),CONSTRAINT course_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (course_id))';
    create_student_course VARCHAR(300) := 'CREATE TABLE student_course(stu_id CHAR(5),course_id VARCHAR(8),section CHAR(3),CONSTRAINT ck_stuid_courseid PRIMARY KEY (stu_id, course_id))';
    insert_student VARCHAR2(1200) := 'INSERT ALL
INTO student VALUES(‘10011’, ‘Smith’, ‘Peter’, ‘M’, ‘M’, ‘Math’, ‘TX’)
INTO student VALUES(‘10012’, ‘Jones’, ‘Sam’, ‘A’, ‘M’, ‘English’, ‘TX’)
INTO student VALUES(‘10013’, ‘Peters’, ‘Amy’, ‘A’, ‘F’, ‘English’, ‘ME’)
INTO student VALUES(‘10014’, ‘Johnson’, ‘John’, ‘J’, ‘M’, ‘CompSci’, ‘CA’)
INTO student VALUES(‘10015’, ‘Penders’, ‘Alton’, ‘P’, ‘F’, ‘Math’, ‘GA’)
INTO student VALUES(‘10016’, ‘Allen’, ‘Diane’, ‘J’, ‘F’, ‘Geography’, ‘Minn’)
INTO student VALUES(‘10017’, ‘Gill’, ‘Jennifer’, ‘‘, ‘F’, ‘CompSci’, ‘TX’)
INTO student VALUES(‘10018’, ‘Johns’, ‘Roberta’, ‘‘, ‘F’, ‘CompSci’, ‘TX’)
INTO student VALUES(‘10019’, ‘Wier’, ‘Paul’, ‘‘, ‘M’, ‘English’, ‘TX’)
SELECT * FROM dual';
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create_student;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create_course;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create_student_course;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insert_student;
END;
/
```

SQL Dev. is giving me this error report:

```
Error report -
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
ORA-06512: at line 17
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Any help would be appreciated. I've been at this for a while now and can't seem to figure it out even with the Oracle book.

Comment: It simply mean that the table with the name that you are trying to create already exists.

Answer (score 1):

1- it means you already have those tables

2- why you are using dynamic sql here? just use regular dml

3- you can wrap each execute with

```
begin
  execute immediate ...;
exception when others then 
  null;
end;
```

4- maybe you should create tables once outside, and run

```
truncate table xxxxx;
```

instead of creating tables, before inserting...

Comment: Believe me, I completely agree, but unfortunately with this assignment my instructor is requiring it be done in a PL/SQL block :\

Comment: so, you want to drop first if it exists? or do you want to skip table creation if it exists? and if it exists, do you want to truncate table?

Comment: Then you have a rather bad instructor. In real code you would never do such thing

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Was a combination of commenting out the table create executes and using q'' to denote string literal.

Answer (score 0):

Instead  of apostrophe you need to use single quote(') in insert statement. Instead of "select * from dual" you need to use "select 1 from dual" and last for multi line sql statement (insert statement) instead of '' you can use (q'[]'). Try below query. It's working.

```
DECLARE
    create_student VARCHAR2(500) := 'CREATE TABLE student(stu_id CHAR(5),Lname VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,Fname VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,Mi VARCHAR(2),Sex CHAR(1),Major VARCHAR(10),Home_State VARCHAR(4),CONSTRAINT stu_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (stu_id))';
    create_course VARCHAR(500) := 'CREATE TABLE course(course_id VARCHAR(8),section CHAR(3)NOT NULL,c_name VARCHAR(30)NOT NULL,c_description VARCHAR(50),CONSTRAINT course_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (course_id))';
    create_student_course VARCHAR(300) := 'CREATE TABLE student_course(stu_id CHAR(5),course_id VARCHAR(8),section CHAR(3),CONSTRAINT ck_stuid_courseid PRIMARY KEY (stu_id, course_id))';
    insert_student VARCHAR2(1200) := q'[INSERT ALL
INTO student VALUES('10011', 'Smith', 'Peter', 'M', 'M', 'Math', 'TX')
INTO student VALUES('10012', 'Jones', 'Sam', 'A', 'M', 'English', 'TX')
INTO student VALUES('10013', 'Peters', 'Amy', 'A', 'F', 'English', 'ME')
INTO student VALUES('10014', 'Johnson', 'John', 'J', 'M', 'CompSci', 'CA')
INTO student VALUES('10015', 'Penders', 'Alton', 'P', 'F', 'Math', 'GA')
INTO student VALUES('10016', 'Allen', 'Diane', 'J', 'F', 'Geography', 'Minn')
INTO student VALUES('10017', 'Gill', 'Jennifer', '', 'F', 'CompSci', 'TX')
INTO student VALUES('10018', 'Johns', 'Roberta', '', 'F', 'CompSci', 'TX')
INTO student VALUES('10019', 'Wier', 'Paul', '', 'M', 'English', 'TX')
SELECT 1 FROM dual]';
begin

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create_student;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE create_student_course;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE insert_student;
   
end;
```